# Using SELECT COUNT after main SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's assume I have x number of stations. They are sending me every x minutes some values. Now I want to read the last value of every station

What I have now is this:

```
SELECT Umweltdaten.id,Umweltdaten.Temperatur,Umweltdaten.DatumZeit, Umweltdaten.gerateID
FROM Umweltdaten
LEFT JOIN Gerate ON Gerate.gerateID = Umweltdaten.gerateID
ORDER BY Umweltdaten.DatumZeit DESC
```

The problem here is it gives me all values

[image: allValues]

But what I need would be limiting this for the number of stations. The stations are listed in another table

Something like this. But it gives me an syntax error. in the line with Limit

```
SELECT Umweltdaten.id,Umweltdaten.Temperatur,Umweltdaten.DatumZeit, Umweltdaten.gerateID
FROM Umweltdaten
LEFT JOIN Gerate ON Gerate.gerateID = Umweltdaten.gerateID
ORDER BY Umweltdaten.DatumZeit DESC
LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(gerateID) FROM Gerate);
```

So that I get this output

[image]

Maybe someone has a solution for my problem.

Note: I don't want to hardcode the LIMIT function because the station number can vary. I'm using phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming "gerate" is your station ID

```
SELECT 
  t.*
FROM
  umweltdaten t
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT max(id) as id FROM umweltdaten GROUP BY gerateid) u
  on t.id = u.id
```

How it works: 
Your id is hopefully an auto incrementing int. this means the max id for any given gerateid is the most recent record. We group by gerateid and pick the max id*. The inner join hence filters the records to only those with a max id per station, giving a result set that is the most recent record per station

*Because id is a primary key we don't need anything else - if the pk were for example a guid (a random number essentially) picking the max one wouldn't work. we would need to select eg gerateid and max date and join on both.

In any greatest-n-per-group query we basically have to find a way to get only the max records. Usually we can't bring in any data other than the thing that qualifies it as the max in the group (max id, max date etc) when we're doing the group operation, so we have to do the group operation as a sub query, get the max records and then join this data representing the max, back to the table to retrieve the rest of the data we want

There are many ways to do this, and one of my favourite ways is to use a row number analytic query but it's not available in MySQL

Comment: gerateID is the station ID, but it works fine, thank you, could you explain your code to me?

Comment: but now I only get data for Umweltdaten, how can i get data from Gerate too?

Comment: Join it in like you would any other query- you can use an unlimited number of joins in a query. Under umweltdaten put `INNER JOIN gerate g ON t.gerateid = g.whatever_id` and put `, g.*` in the select area

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using 'Gerate' in your join condition because you are not using in your select statement

You will need Prepared Statements like this-

```
SELECT COUNT(gerateID) into @limitcount FROM Gerate
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT Umweltdaten.id,Umweltdaten.Temperatur,Umweltdaten.DatumZeit, Umweltdaten.gerateID
FROM Umweltdaten LIMIT ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @limitcount ;
```